# Replace values located close to themselves with the mean value

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if SO is the proper place for asking this, if it's not, I will remove the question and try it in some other place. Said that I'm trying to do the following:

[image]

I have a `List<double>` and want to replace the block of values whose values are situated very close (say 0.75 in this example) to a single value, representing the mean of the replaced values.
The values that are isolated, or alone, should not be modified.
Also the replaced block can't be longer than 5.

Computing the mean value for each interval from 0, 5, 10.. would not provide the expected results.

It happened many times that LINQ power surprised me gladly and I would be happy if someone could guide me in the creation of this little method.

What I've thought is to first find the closest values for each one, calculate the distance, if the distance is less than minimum (0.75 in this example) then assign those values to the same block.

When all values are assigned to their blocks run a second loop that replaces each block (with one value, or many values) to its mean.

The problem that I have in this approach is to assign the "block": if several values are together, I need to check if the evaluating value is contained in another block, and if it so, the new value should be in that block too.
I don't know if this is the right way of doing this or I'm over complicating it.

EDIT: the expected result:
[image]

Although you see two axes only one is used, the List is 1D, I should have drawn only the X axis.

The length of the lines that are represented is irrelevant. It's just to mark on the axis where the value is situated.

Comment: I'm suffering from a bit of information overload here.  Would it be accurate to say that you are asking how to remove items in a `List<double>` that are within .75 of a given value?  If not, could you provide an example of your list before and after?

Comment: Sorry, but not quite. A given value is not provided and it's not to just remove the values, but replacing them with their mean value. Also there are a limitation of the length of the interval of the replaced values.

Comment: Hrrm, I'd need to see an example of your list before and after processing to give an accurate answer.

Comment: @Sturm as I understand the data may be like a `stream` of `byte` (or something like that), so this looks like not suitable for a `LINQ` solution, just process it *lively*.

Comment: @Sturm does the original order in the list play any role in selecting a "block"? From your example plot it would appear that it is not simply a list of doubles. Can you explain what exactly is plotted there (x-axis, y-axis value).

Comment: @Strum I got the your problem. According to me, first sort the number.Then take a scan and compare the adjacent value if there difference is less than as u specified(0.75 in your example), then take that in block.Do this until u find the value whose difference is more.And then find the mean. It's obvious that mean must lies in between the that block so it can't go into the another block.

Comment: I've represented it badly, only X information is relevant. I forgot the mention that the list is ordered, so the order "doesn't matter".

Comment: @JatinKhurana that would seem like workable strategy to me. One little addition: if the number of values (still within the .75 range) already taken exceed the limit of 5, take the average and move on to the next.

Comment: What would you _want_ to happen if there was a 6-long stretch of a couple of close values?

Comment: @Alex yes... I don't see Sturm mentioned the block of size 5.

Comment: And is the image just to give us an idea, or did you not really mean 0.75 ? (because some of them look farther apart.)

Comment: @JatinKhurana re block of 5: from the question "Also the replaced block can't be longer than 5"

Comment: Maybe this will interest you: http://www.markschulze.net/java/whatismlv.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that MSDN has already done this, and provided an in-depth example application with code:

[Data Clustering - Detecting Abnormal Data Using k-Means Clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891054.aspx)

Comment: The presented problem is not an instance of k-means problem. At least, we don't know `k` a priori.